# Cross Browser WebRTC DataChannel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm not being able to create a RTC dataChannel between Chrome and Firefox. I had success creating video and audio streams between the two browsers, but not the dataChannel.

If the communication is between two Firefox browsers or two Chrome browser, it works. Is it possible to create a dataChannel between those two?

Thanks.

Comment: wondering if you figured out the issue

Comment: maybe you can add some code or jsfiddle or any demo that helps.

Comment: Same as @moath suggests. Because it's totally possible to create a DataChannel between Chrome and Firefox.  Are you using SCTP instead of RTP ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to create data channels between Chrome and Firefox. There's a bit of custom code required to achieve connectivity but it's not too bad.

I recommend using a module that smooths over the differences and simplifies the WebRTC API. I wrote [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer) for this purpose. You can take a look at [index.js](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer/blob/master/index.js) to see where there is custom logic to handle Chrome or Firefox quirks.

Another popular solution is [adapter.js](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js?r=3905) (created by Google), which attempts to smooth out the differences between browsers without making the API easier to user.